# Protractor non angular tests do not obey waits and sleeps until there is an error in the code

Tags: javascript, angular, automation, protractor, cucumber

I am using Protractor and cucumber for automation tests on some non angular pages. I have set browser.ignoreSynchronization to true.

When I run a scenario only the first line which is browser.get(...) is executed correctly. I can see the URL loads fine. All following steps are not executed (as I don't see them run in browser) but I see all green and all passed in the results. None of the waits and sleeps in the code have any effect on execution.

However if there is an error somewhere in the code, lets say in the last step of scenario/stepdef I have wrong code **browser.blah.something();** then I can see all sleeps and waits being obeyed.

I don't understand what is going on! Why does this erroneous code cause Protractor to obey timeouts? Why this weird behavior? Any idea? Also just wondering why **browser.blah.something()** doesn't cause compile time error (error before tests start)?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can put some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those errors are most likely things like syntax or type errors, things that are parsed prior to execution and not failures in your tests.

There's a lot of reasons why your following lines are not working, we can't say what unless you show us the code.

My guess here is that the bunch of codes that follow your first line are promises. In fact, wait(http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) itself returns a promise.

Promises run asynchronously and not synchronously which is what you might have been expecting.

Here's a short example of what might be happening:

-> App accesses the url

-> App waits for 5 seconds (let's say this is a promise)

-> close the app

You might expect the app to access the url and then wait for 5 seconds then close but what will actually happen is the app will access the url then immediately close.

Why? because the wait for 5 seconds was executed on another thread and the main thread never waited for the 5 seconds to be done (javascript is single-threaded but... you could read about it somewhere)

To counter this, you can chain them (https://javascript.info/promise-chaining) or use async/await, depending on the es version you are following.

I won't delve into promises since that doesn't seem to be the target question here but in case promises are the reason, here's a great [article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) to get started on it

**And to answer why browser.something() is not giving an error**, [browser](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.get) is actually ProtractorBrowser.prototype, I won't delve into it since it'll be a long answer but again, here's a great [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

Try doing the following

```
console.log(browser)
browser.something = "abc"
console.log(browser)
```

the second log should show a new property, 'something' with a value of "abc"

Comment: Thanks kdyz. Will give it a try. It could be async promises as you said.

Answer (score 0):

It is better now to use

```
browser. waitForAngularEnabled(false)
```

instead of

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
```

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngularEnabled

Also, try to put this into beforeEach()

```
describe('my suite', ()=>{
    beforeEach(()=> {
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)
    })
    it('my test', ()=> {
        ...
    })
})
```

I can suggest putting this into
`onPrepare` section of your config file or into `beforeEach` block. So it will be set before running all tests.

```
//Your protractor configuration file
let conf = {
// Some other options ...
    onPrepare: () => {
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Madhan, I have infact added ignoreSynchronization as part of before hook. I have also tried with waitForAngularEnabled. The result is still the same. It doesn't wait. I have to try what kdyz says below. Since its async it being done on diff thread and its not waiting. Got to have a look at promise chaining and async wait.